# Element type is invalid, react

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone help me, I'm trying to make a react table, but it says that the element type is invalid.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/live/uop3pdt

Answer (score 0):

React table is now headless, which means you have to define the HTML structure and it only provides the logic using hooks. If you want the old fashioned react table, use [react-table-v6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-v6) instead.